# How to add description to Glue on AWS using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I am using the following command to save a table using pyspark

```
        .saveAsTable(
            'db_temp.tb_temp',
            format='parquet',
            path='s3://datalake-123/table/df/',
            mode='overwrite'
        )
```

However, I would also like to save the **table description** in Glue, just like the picture bellow shows:

[image]

Comment: So your table is ebing save to glue (via s3) from emr but doesn't have description, right?

Comment: Exactly! I'm saving it from EMR.